# How can I change the value of an NSString every N seconds using?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsarray, nstimer

I have this code to change the number in the `NSString` every five seconds.

How will I keep the numbers running in a loop? It now runs from 1 to 19 ,and stops at the last one (19) with a SIGABRT on the line: `label.text = ...`

How can I start with the first number displayed (0), before the first timer fires?

Here is the code:

```
-(IBAction) rotate3

{


    NSString *number = [self.dayArray description];

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"0", @"1", @"2",..., @"19",nil];

    number =  @"0" ;
    numberCount++ ;


    self.dayArray = array;
    [array release];


    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day: %@ ", [dayArray objectAtIndex   :numberCount ]];


}

//and the timer

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(rotate3 )userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your .h file, in your interface (that is, if it isn't already there)

```
{
    NSInteger numberCount
}
```

Then in your viewDidLoad method, initialize numberCount and the label:

```
numberCount = 0;
label.text = @"0";
```

And in your time method, replace:

```
numberCount++
```

with

```
if(numberCount++ > 19)
    numberCount = 0;
```

What is the "number" NSString used for, b.t.w.?

Comment: I just change that but now is counting 2,4,6,8...20,0

Comment: you have duplicate numberCount++ lines in your timer method.  remove one of them.  :-)

Comment: whoops... I forgot that not everyone here will understand our crazy American slang. ["b.t.w."](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=btw) means "by the way" or "in addition".

Comment: Thanks Michael. Now is working great this is how the code looks like    NSString *number = [self.dayArray description];
    
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4",..., @"19",nil];
    
     number = [dayArray objectAtIndex : numberCount];
    
    numberCount++;
   label.text = @"0";
   
    if (numberCount >19) numberCount = 0;

   
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day: %@ ", [dayArray objectAtIndex : numberCount]];
 
    self.dayArray = array;
    [array release];

Comment: Number NSString is used to show the days in a Maya Month. They used 0 to 19 to number the days.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answers:

1)I think, at the last one (19), the numberCount is 20 (numberCount++ ;).
2)Just set the value before scheduling the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Why have dayArray?
why not something like

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day: %d", numberCount++];
if (numberCount>19) numberCount = 0;
```

I don't know what you have number count initialized to it should probably be -1 and also reinitialized to -1 . if you wish to iterate thru "Day: 0" ... "Day: 19"
It's not clear.

Comment: In Mayan calendar day count is from 0 to 19

Comment: Using that, numbers goes crazy

Answer (score 0):

You could change the -(void)viewDidLoad timer to not repeat

```
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(rotate3 )userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

then, conditionally set it up again in the rotate3 method if you still want to change the text 5 seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#pragma mark - timer callback

-(IBAction)rotate3
{
    [label1 setText:[dayArray objectAtIndex:numberCount]];
    numberCount++;
    if (numberCount >= [dayArray count])
        numberCount = 0;
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dayArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
    [label1 setText:[dayArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    numberCount = 1;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(rotate3) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Somebody else downvoted this but I'm re-upvoting this, because @antonio makes a great point.  Setting an array like this in a timer method (every time) is incredibly inefficient.  Best to create the array once (in the `viewDidLoad` method, for example).

Comment: Thanks Antonio, I will try and let you know.

Comment: I finish trying the code the way you suggest and works fine, just added NSString stringWithFormat...after setText :  Thanks Antonio